# Insertion-sort in java with helper method don't work. Anyone see what I'm missing?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

Somehow this sorting algorithm doesn't produce a sorted result. Anyone see why? There is a getAge() method and age field in the class I have excluded here.

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person)
    {
        int anotherAge = person.getAge();
        return (age<anotherAge ? -1 : (age==anotherAge ? 0 : 1));

    }
}
public static Person[] insertionSort(Person[] list)
{
    int i, j;
    Person key, temp;
    for(i = 1; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        key= list[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(list[i].compareTo(list[j]) < 0)
        {
            temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[j+1];
            list[j+1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: My guess -- on the second iteration, after j becomes negative (after `j--;`) you are getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception in `while(list[i].compareTo(list[j]) <0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is quick fix for your problem since it seems u  were decrementing j keeping i constant

so for exampke
 array =1 2 0 4

i is pointing to 0   j is pointing to 2

i keeps on pointing to same index after every swap and j keeps on decrementing
because of that there was problem in swapping it should be between adjecent element not distant element

```
 key= list[i];
        j = i-1;
       int k=i;
        while(j>=0&& list[k].compareTo(list[j]) < 0 )
        {
            temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[j+1];
            list[j+1] = temp;
            j--;
        k--;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to solve a problem thats already been solved.

How about

`Arrays.sort(list)`

Alternatively if you want it in the reverse order from your `comparable` implementation.

`Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(Arrays.sort(list));`

Insertion sort implies that the structure that you're inserting to will sort whilst you're inserting to it. From what we can see in your example code it seems more like youre trying to sort after some insertions. 
If you want insertion sort I'd recommend a [treeset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) assuming you have unique items in your list.